# How to use org-refile to move a headline to a file as a toplevel headline?

Tags: org-mode

I wish to have an "inbox.org" file where I collect notes into (trying to implement [GTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) :P), and then later move things around to the proper places. I understand that `org-refile` is the way to do this (move things around), but it seems that it is only possible to refile stuff under headlines, not directly into files. What I want is to take a note from my inbox.org and add it as a toplevel heading in the proper org file.

Is this by any chance possible? I read the info on `org-refile-targets` and it seems like it is only able to refile into an existing headline, although the info on `org-refile-use-outline-path` says:

> org-refile-use-outline-path is a variable defined in `org.el'. Its
>   value is "file" Original value was nil
>
> Documentation: Non-nil means provide refile targets as paths. So a
>   level 3 headline will be available as level1/level2/level3.
>
> When the value is `file', also include the file name (without
>   directory) into the path.  In this case, you can also stop the
>   completion after the file name, **to get entries inserted as top level**
>   in the file.

However, autocompletion on the `org-refile` prompt does not even provide the file names as options. Is there a way to do this with `org-refile-targets` or any other means?

I'm running gnu emacs 24.5.1 on windows 8.1 64bit.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured out the small detail I was missing. The docs say

> When the value is `file', also include the file name (without
>   directory) into the path.

I misinterpreted this as `"file"`, which had no effect on the refile targets presented to me. What should be the value of `org-refile-use-outline-path` is actually `'file`, the quoted symbol `file`!! :)

Hope this saves someone the time I wasted looking for the solution to a non-existent problem. Anyway, the documentation should not have that single quote character after `'file`.

I discovered the solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334817/emacs-org-mode-refile-to-main-tree-and-not-as-a-subtree) to the same question on stackoverflow, so maybe it is still useful to post it here.

Comment: @trepador   
I have also had this problem, and thank you for solving my problem. I use `(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file) `